# Magento wants to reinstall after migration

Tags: php, mysql, magento, installation, magento-1.6

In the last days I moved a Magento installation over a new staging server and a new production server. Everything went well on the production server, where the site is back againg, but I'm not able to make it work on the staging server... It keeps saying that the table "admin_assert" is already present (mysql error) and the error comes from the install script... but I don't want another install.

How's it possible that magento is trying to perform an installation over another preconfigured base?

I moved the whole base (source code), without performing a clean install, then I dumped the DB and changed the base urls.

Do you have any idea?

FYI this is the whole error log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:193:"Error in file:  "/home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'admin_assert' already exists";i:1;s:920:"#0 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.1.0')
#2 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.1.0')
#3 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(412): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(338): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/lex/code/mycommerce/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big deal. You will find many more errors like this.

The error simple says your DB already has table name `admin_assert`.

You can ignore this by opening the install script and comment out the code which tries to re-create the table, and refresh the magento again.

Once everything is set up properly, don't forget to uncomment the commented create table script.

Comment: So I need to make the script run again? I don't want it to clean my db, because I'm not reinstalling it :-s Why is it asking that on the staging server but it worked well on the other server?

Comment: that's because in your `core_resource` table, there is no entry for this `admin_assert` table so Magento would not know that this module is already set up. To make Magento know, you can try to update the column of this table in `core_resouce` table with appropriate version number (the number you find at config.xml version tag) and then clearing cache.

Comment: Can you help me to find which config.xml should I look at? I'm searching it, but I have no idea what should I search for...

Comment: `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml` and setup script `mysql4-install-0.7.0.php`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well with a rather large database and it turned out that PHPMyAdmin was unable to export the entire thing at the same time, so my data was incomplete. The solution in my case was to export tables in batches instead of all at once, and then import them in the same way.

**tl;dr**
Make sure that your databases match